# Does the geodatabase administrator login rebuild indexes for datasets not owned by the login?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, maintenance

According to the ESRI documentation, the [Rebuild Indexes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/rebuild-indexes.htm) tool

> is used in databases and enterprise, workgroup, and desktop
>   geodatabases to rebuild existing attribute or spatial indexes. In
>   enterprise, workgroup, and desktop geodatabases, indexes can also be
>   rebuilt on states and state_lineage geodatabase system tables and the
>   delta tables of versioned datasets.

It goes on to say that the tool rebuilds the attribute and spatial indexes of base tables, delta tables, and archive tables in versioned and archive-enabled geodatabases, as well as System Tables (if the parameter is checked).  However, [this](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-postgresql/rebuild-system-table-indexes.htm) and [this](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/rebuilding-dataset-indexes.htm) documentation make it seem like the tool does different things if run as gdb admin vs. data owner.

In my enterprise environment, my database admin does not own data, and as such does not have options to manage the dataset via Catalog in ArcMap.

Does the geodatabase administrator login rebuild indexes for datasets not owned by the login?

**EDIT**:  Similarly, [another esri example](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_Python_scripting_to_batch_reconcile_and_post_versions/003n000000v7000000/) uses gdb admin to run the tool on system tables as well as a list of datasets (code sample below), which is what is confusing me.  I agree with what Vince is saying in the comments, but can someone verify what the tool is capable of doing?

```
# Execute rebuild indexes and analyze datasets
# Note: to use the "SYSTEM" option the user must be an administrator.

workspace = "Database Connections/admin.sde"

arcpy.RebuildIndexes_management(workspace, "SYSTEM", dataList, "ALL")

arcpy.AnalyzeDatasets_management(workspace, "SYSTEM", dataList, "ANALYZE_BASE", "ANALYZE_DELTA", "ANALYZE_ARCHIVE")
```

Comment: The geodatabase admin owns and manages the geodatabase metadata. The data owner manages the data owned by that user. I never grant the SDE login privileges to do anything like index management for other users.

Comment: So if I use the tool, either via ArcMap or arcpy, with admin privileges, it will rebuild indexes for all feature datasets AND system tables? The documentation is rather ambiguous.

Comment: No, that was not my point at all. Metadata index is an admin responsibility. Data index is an owner responsibility. Each to their own. This is complicated by the details you haven't provided, so it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I know different setups have different requirements, so I don't want to start a discussion about responsibilities.  My data owner and database administrator are essentially the same person, and I only created the data owner role based on ESRI recommendations.  I simply want to know if the admin runs the above tool, will it index all datasets and system tables.

Comment: I doubt it. Nor should it.